# Help needed for getting the blackberry webworks push demo to work with Urban Airship

Tags: blackberry, push, blackberry-webworks

I have gotten the Push Demo from [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/How-to-Create-a-Push-BlackBerry-WebWorks-application/ta-p/494141) to work in the simulators.

When I tried it on a blackberry device (BlackBerry Bold 9000) with the UrbanAirship Test Push messages, I was not able to receive any push notifications.

Things that I have done so far are:
    * Changed the push port from 100 to 29580
    * Added the application id as an attribute to the widget element in config.xml
    * The application has been signed before uploaded to the phone.
    * I'm assuming no errors in the code because both start/stop subscribe alert messages appear on app start/button click
    * There is no indication of network activity when a test message has been sent by UrbanAirship.

My config.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" id="{app_id}">
    <name>Push Example</name>
    <description>Samples of code</description>
    <author href="http://www.rim.com/" rim:copyright="no copyright" email="webapi@rim.com">
    Research in Motion - Web API Team
    </author><content src="index.htm" />
    <feature id="blackberry.system" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
    <feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
    <feature id="blackberry.invoke.JavaArguments" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
    <feature id="blackberry.invoke.CalendarArguments" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
    <feature id="blackberry.invoke" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
    <feature id="blackberry.push" version="1.0.0"/>
    <feature id="blackberry.identity" version="1.0.0"/>
    <feature id="blackberry.utils" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
    <rim:connection timeout="30000">
        <id>MDS</id>
        <id>BIS-B</id>
        <id>TCP_WIFI</id>
        <id>TCP_CELLULAR</id>
        <id>WAP2</id>
        <id>WAP</id>
    </rim:connection>
    <license href="http://www.license.com">This is a sample license</license>
</widget>
```

The action.js file looks like this:

```
//the port that the Push Listener will listen to on the MDS
//Open the rimpublic.property file, which is located in the MDS\config subdirectory
//of your BlackBerry Email and MDS Services Simulators installation directory.
//Ensure the "push.application.reliable.ports=100" line is NOT commented out.
var port = 29580;

function subscribe() {
    //open the listener to listen if there is pushed data coming through
    blackberry.push.openPushListener(handleReturnData, port);
    try {
        alert("push listening has started. push port = ("+port+") app id = (" + blackberry.app.id + ") pin = ("+blackberry.identity.PIN+")");
    } catch (e) {
        alert (e);
    }
}

//handleReturnData - the function to call for the event of pushed data coming through
//port - the port to listen on
function handleReturnData(data) {
    try {
        if (data != null) {
            var text = blackberry.utils.blobToString(data.payload);
            alert("text recieved from push: " + text);
        } else {
            alert("No data from the push");
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert (e);
    }
}

function unsubscribe() {
    //stop listening for pushed data, a clean up step
    blackberry.push.closePushListener(port);
    alert("Push listening has stopped");
}
```

Finally, my index.html file looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Push Example</title>
        <script src="Scripts/action.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="Styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body onload="javascript&colon;subscribe();">
        <button id="btnUnsubscribe" onclick="unsubscribe();">Unsubscribe</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Would anyone know what could be wrong with my code/configuration?

Cheers,
Stephen

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blackberry Web Works how to fire event everytime the app is launched](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545423/blackberry-web-works-how-to-fire-event-everytime-the-app-is-launched)